# Git couldn't connect to github

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I wang to clong project from Github for learning, but when I have downloaded Git, I try to connect it to Github but failed, and the error message in the picture: No such a file or directory. But my computer doesn't have the application(emacs). And it always links to this path whatever I do. 
I have seen much similarly questions, but not the same as my error. How should I solve it?
[image]

Comment: Does something here help? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssh%5D+ssh-keygen+Saving+key+failed%3A+No+such+file+or+directory

Comment: $ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "XXXXXXX@163.com"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/d/360安全浏览器下载/emacs-22.3-barebin-i386/.ssh/id_rsa):
Could not create directory '/d/360\345\256\211\345\205\250\346\265\217\350\247\210\345\231\250\344\270\213\350\275\275/emacs-22.3-barebin-i386/.ssh': No such file or directory
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Saving key "/d/360\345\256\211\345\205\250\346\265\217\350\247\210\345\231\250\344\270\213\350\275\275/emacs-22.3-barebin-i386/.ssh/id_rsa" failed: No such file or directory

Comment: Check (and fix) environment variable `$HOME`. Start with `echo $HOME`

Comment: $ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "xxxxxx@163.com" -f /path/to/key
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Saving key "/path/to/key" failed: No such file or directory

Comment: $ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "xxxxxx@163.com"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (//.ssh/id_rsa):
Could not create directory '//.ssh': Read-only file system
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Saving key "//.ssh/id_rsa" failed: No such file or directory

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssh%5D+Could+not+create+directory+%27%2F%2F.ssh%27%3A+Read-only+file+system

Comment: I have tried it. but it doesn't works.

Comment: $ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "xxxxxx@163.com" -f /path/to/key
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Saving key "/path/to/key" failed: No such file or directory

Comment: hhh, I have solved the problem accidentally. Thanks everyone!